# converting decimal to hexadecimal value

Tags: php, colors, hex

I need to convert the "age" of an item (in days), into an hexadecimal value, where oldest item = max color = D9D8C9, and most recent = min color = FFFFFF.

items beyond age 365 get color D9D8C9.
items beneath age 7 get color FFFFFF.

According to these min and max colors, how can i find the color of any item younger than 365 days and older than 7 days?

Eventually, I'll do it in PHP but pseudocode example is fine.

Comment: Younger than 365 days and older than 7 days? Is this only your condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, you're looking for a way to arbitrarily *map* one range onto another (7-365 should be mapped of `FFFFFF` - `D9D8D9`).

First things first: converting decimal to hex is quite easy:

```
$age = mt_rand(1,600);
if ($age > 365) $hex = 'D9D8D9';
elseif ($age < 7) $hex = 'FFFFFF';
else $hex = str_pad(dechex($age), 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

What I do is simply check if `$age` is greater then 365, if so, I assign the `D9D8D9` constant, if it's less than 7, I assign `FFFFFF`. In all other cases, I simply convert the number to hexadecimal, and pad the resulting string to 6 chars, using `0`, so `255` would become `FF`, and is padded to `0000FF`.

But to map a range on a range, we'll have to find out how a step of *1* in the smallest range scales to the larger one(s). It's a simple *"rule of three"*: calculate the equivalent of 1 in both scales, and multiply. Then apply the same range-bounds and you're there.
The colour-range you're using is `FFFFFF` through `D9D8D9`, or to put it in decimals: `16777215` through `14276809`. This leaves us with a range of `2500406`, versus 365-7 (or 358) days. Each single day, therefore is *"worth"* `6984.374301676` (`(D9D8D9-FFFFFF)/(365-7)`) in our colour range.
Put it all together and you have 2 options: calculate the distance from FFFFFF or D9D8D9, but as far as the result is concerned, it doesn't matter which one you choose.

```
<CrLowBound> - (<value>-<VLowBound>)*<CrStep>
//or
<CrHighBound> - (<VHighBound> - <value>)*<CrStep>
```

Both simply compute the value in the colour range that corresponds to the given value. `CrLowBound` and `CrHighBound` are FFF and D9D8D9 respectively, in much the same way: `VLowBound` and `VHighBound` are 6 and 366. `CrStep` is `6984.374301676`. I've explained how I got these values.

```
$age = mt_rand(1,600);
if ($age > 365) $hex = 'D9D8D9';
elseif ($age < 7) $hex = 'FFFFFF';
else $hex = str_pad(dechex(14276809-(round((366-$dec)*6984.374301676))), 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
//Or:
$hex = str_pad(dechex(16777215-(round(($dec-6)*6984.374301676))), 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

This will more evenly spread the range of colours within the `D9D8D9` to `FFFFFF` range: the older the item, the closer the color will be to `D9D8D9`, the more recent, the closer it is to `FFFFFF`.
For example, if the age is `117`, the *"colour"* will be `1A6E1D`:

```
//age    (max-age)*worth   hex
  117  ==  1732125   ==   1a6e1d
```

Tested with the following code:

```
function getColour($dec)
{
    if ($dec > 365) return 'D9D8D9';
    if ($dec < 7) return 'FFFFFF';
    return strtoupper(
        str_pad(
            dechex(14276809-(round((366-$dec)*6984.374301676))),
            6,
            '0',
            STR_PAD_LEFT
        )
    );
}
$days = range(6,366);
$colours = array();
foreach($days as $day) $colours[$day] = getColour($day);
$out = array_chunk($colours, 8);
foreach($out as $k => $chunk) $out[$k] = implode(' - ', $chunk);
echo implode('<br>', $out);
```

And got this as output:

```
FFFFFF - B3964B - B3B193 - B3CCDB - B3E824 - B4036C - B41EB4 - B439FD
B45545 - B4708E - B48BD6 - B4A71E - B4C267 - B4DDAF - B4F8F7 - B51440
B52F88 - B54AD1 - B56619 - B58161 - B59CAA - B5B7F2 - B5D33A - B5EE83
B609CB - B62514 - B6405C - B65BA4 - B676ED - B69235 - B6AD7D - B6C8C6
B6E40E - B6FF57 - B71A9F - B735E7 - B75130 - B76C78 - B787C0 - B7A309
B7BE51 - B7D99A - B7F4E2 - B8102A - B82B73 - B846BB - B86203 - B87D4C
B89894 - B8B3DD - B8CF25 - B8EA6D - B905B6 - B920FE - B93C46 - B9578F
B972D7 - B98E20 - B9A968 - B9C4B0 - B9DFF9 - B9FB41 - BA1689 - BA31D2
BA4D1A - BA6863 - BA83AB - BA9EF3 - BABA3C - BAD584 - BAF0CC - BB0C15
BB275D - BB42A6 - BB5DEE - BB7936 - BB947F - BBAFC7 - BBCB0F - BBE658
BC01A0 - BC1CE9 - BC3831 - BC5379 - BC6EC2 - BC8A0A - BCA552 - BCC09B
BCDBE3 - BCF72C - BD1274 - BD2DBC - BD4905 - BD644D - BD7F95 - BD9ADE
BDB626 - BDD16F - BDECB7 - BE07FF - BE2348 - BE3E90 - BE59D8 - BE7521
BE9069 - BEABB2 - BEC6FA - BEE242 - BEFD8B - BF18D3 - BF341B - BF4F64
BF6AAC - BF85F5 - BFA13D - BFBC85 - BFD7CE - BFF316 - C00E5E - C029A7
C044EF - C06038 - C07B80 - C096C8 - C0B211 - C0CD59 - C0E8A1 - C103EA
C11F32 - C13A7B - C155C3 - C1710B - C18C54 - C1A79C - C1C2E4 - C1DE2D
C1F975 - C214BE - C23006 - C24B4E - C26697 - C281DF - C29D27 - C2B870
C2D3B8 - C2EF01 - C30A49 - C32591 - C340DA - C35C22 - C3776A - C392B3
C3ADFB - C3C944 - C3E48C - C3FFD4 - C41B1D - C43665 - C451AD - C46CF6
C4883E - C4A387 - C4BECF - C4DA17 - C4F560 - C510A8 - C52BF0 - C54739
C56281 - C57DCA - C59912 - C5B45A - C5CFA3 - C5EAEB - C60633 - C6217C
C63CC4 - C6580D - C67355 - C68E9D - C6A9E6 - C6C52E - C6E076 - C6FBBF
C71707 - C7324F - C74D98 - C768E0 - C78429 - C79F71 - C7BAB9 - C7D602
C7F14A - C80C92 - C827DB - C84323 - C85E6C - C879B4 - C894FC - C8B045
C8CB8D - C8E6D5 - C9021E - C91D66 - C938AF - C953F7 - C96F3F - C98A88
C9A5D0 - C9C118 - C9DC61 - C9F7A9 - CA12F2 - CA2E3A - CA4982 - CA64CB
CA8013 - CA9B5B - CAB6A4 - CAD1EC - CAED35 - CB087D - CB23C5 - CB3F0E
CB5A56 - CB759E - CB90E7 - CBAC2F - CBC778 - CBE2C0 - CBFE08 - CC1951
CC3499 - CC4FE1 - CC6B2A - CC8672 - CCA1BB - CCBD03 - CCD84B - CCF394
CD0EDC - CD2A24 - CD456D - CD60B5 - CD7BFE - CD9746 - CDB28E - CDCDD7
CDE91F - CE0467 - CE1FB0 - CE3AF8 - CE5641 - CE7189 - CE8CD1 - CEA81A
CEC362 - CEDEAA - CEF9F3 - CF153B - CF3084 - CF4BCC - CF6714 - CF825D
CF9DA5 - CFB8ED - CFD436 - CFEF7E - D00AC7 - D0260F - D04157 - D05CA0
D077E8 - D09330 - D0AE79 - D0C9C1 - D0E50A - D10052 - D11B9A - D136E3
D1522B - D16D73 - D188BC - D1A404 - D1BF4D - D1DA95 - D1F5DD - D21126
D22C6E - D247B6 - D262FF - D27E47 - D29990 - D2B4D8 - D2D020 - D2EB69
D306B1 - D321F9 - D33D42 - D3588A - D373D3 - D38F1B - D3AA63 - D3C5AC
D3E0F4 - D3FC3C - D41785 - D432CD - D44E16 - D4695E - D484A6 - D49FEF
D4BB37 - D4D67F - D4F1C8 - D50D10 - D52859 - D543A1 - D55EE9 - D57A32
D5957A - D5B0C2 - D5CC0B - D5E753 - D6029C - D61DE4 - D6392C - D65475
D66FBD - D68B05 - D6A64E - D6C196 - D6DCDF - D6F827 - D7136F - D72EB8
D74A00 - D76548 - D78091 - D79BD9 - D7B722 - D7D26A - D7EDB2 - D808FB
D82443 - D83F8B - D85AD4 - D8761C - D89165 - D8ACAD - D8C7F5 - D8E33E
D8FE86 - D919CE - D93517 - D9505F - D96BA8 - D986F0 - D9A238 - D9BD81
D9D8D9
```

[Codepad with 2 versions of this code](http://codepad.org/PyEDlRZx)

Comment: The second scenario is actually exactly what i am looking for. I'm testing it now.

Comment: @pixeline: No need, I already did, and posted the results. Note that an item with age 365 will yield `000000` -> the older the item gets, the more in converges on black, so instead of subtracting from 365, you might want subtract from the D9D8D9 constant, but that's up to you, of course... (`dechex(14276809-(round((366-$dec)*6984.374301676)))`, because D9D8D9 is 14276809)

Comment: simply stunned by how simple you've made it sound. Awesome answer!

Comment: @pixeline: [I've set up this codepad](http://codepad.org/PyEDlRZx), too, which uses both versions. functions are aptly named `convergeOnBlack` and `convergeOnGray`... see which one you actually need